# SQL Server Change Data Capture order of records

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

Does anybody know if change data capture functions return always data in the order of occurence?. In a CDC system is quite important to get the data modifications in the order they have been generated.

Looking to the cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_XXX functions, there is no order by clause in any of the underlying queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote from the manual:

[Track Data Changes (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

> Change tracking is based on committed transactions. The order of the changes 
>   is based on transaction commit time. This allows for reliable results to
>   be obtained when there are long-running and overlapping transactions.
>   Custom solutions that use timestamp values must be specifically
>   designed to handle these scenarios.

and [cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says:

> Commit LSN associated with the change that preserves the commit order of the 
>   change. Changes committed in the same transaction share the same commit LSN 
>   value.

for one of the returned columns (`_$start_lsn`) in `get_all_changes`.

Answer (score 1):

Found it documented:

> The function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ returns all
>   changes that occurred for the specified interval. This function is
>   always generated. **Entries are always returned sorted**, first by the
>   transaction commit LSN of the change, and then by a value that
>   sequences the change within its transaction.

[Work with Change Data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Of course if you embed the query against the change function in a larger query, you have to explicitly order the results.